# Convert localizable.strings to spreadsheet?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, internationalization

Is there a standard way to convert the localizable.strings file to csv format, or something else than can be imported by a spreadsheet program such as OpenOffice? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just import in your spreadsheet program and use the "=" character as delimiter between the two columns. Just make sure that your spreadsheet program preserves UTF-8 or UTF-16 characters when importing and exporting.

Comment: Also remember to check the import setting in Excel to tell it to use the Double Quotes character as a string delimiter.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with OpenOffice, but sounds like a good solution for others so thanks anyway :-)

Comment: A bit late but FWIW it works with LibreOffice version 4.3.4.1

Answer (score 13):

A bit outdated answer, but this online tool, does the job better and faster:

http://localise.biz/free/converter/ios-to-android

Comment: Super useful. Thanks!

Comment: Crashing today, not parsing iOS dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent the last few hours installing and playing with [Babelish](https://github.com/netbe/Babelish), a ruby script to do this. I'm still looking around a bit, because I really wish it preserved the comments in my .strings file, but I thought I'd comment here anyway.