# Swift: Parse .strings file to .csv file using Command Line Tool

Tags: swift, csv

I need to convert my `Localizable.strings` file to .csv file. 
Can i do it using `SwiftGen` API? What it the best solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem and all the tools I tried did not work. Some for example most tools/technics did not take in to account the comments from the developer that are included in the `strings` file.
So I ended up developing my own tool [csv2strings](https://github.com/csknns/csv2strings), that converts Apple's strings file to and from csv files.

Just downloaded it and run:

```
swift run csv2strings Localizable2.strings
```

Answer (score 0):

This question could probably use a bit of clarification, Birdy.  For example:  how often do you need to do this and do you need to do this automatically (as part of building a project) or manually & only occasionally.

Anyways, to answer, the SwiftGen documentation on [top of it's repo](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) says nothing about CSV formats, so that's not going to help you.

.strings files are in the format of `key=value`, so you could simply open the .strings file in your favorite text editor (e.g. Xcode!) and  you could use find/replace to replace "=" with a tab character.  There's also a couple other solutions found [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117761/convert-localizable-strings-to-spreadsheet).

Comment: My idea is to run the script file in terminal and convert all Localizable.strings files for each language in my project to csv file. Then convert them to xml.

Comment: thanx for replay 

Comment: Sounds like [the Babelfish tool](https://github.com/netbe/Babelish) (also referred to in my linked question) might really help you.

Comment: babelfish tool i could not install... why do i need to replace "=" with tab?

Comment: "=" replace with ",", and ";" with tab?

Comment: then i have one table with two columns (1-key and 2-value), right?